# ping a *.local address client

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have a bind9 dns cache server running (for example with zone ".home" and any clients with ubuntu and raspberian. Additionally some other clients with Mac OS, Windows etc.

I can ping all units by IP address. I can't ping all units by xxx.local. I can ping all units by its xxx.home name (if it is  defined in the DNS zone). But ..

I have one unit (IoT Device) that is defined with a xxx.home DNS entry. I can ping that unit by IP address, by its *.home name, but not with xxx.local.

What could be the reason?

I thought, *.local is an apple mDNS implementation, so a client, that can be reached by apple services (on ubuntu for example with avahi implementation), should response on *.local requests. The IoT device has a IOS app, so should have a mDNS implementation, so should react on *.local ping?
avahi-browse -a didnt show that IoT device, but the IOS mobile app to communicate with that device works.

Comment: It need not support mDNS just because it has an iOS app. The communication could be via the internet and third party servers, or some other discovery mechanism.

Comment: That true. But in my case it's a simple wget request to the ip address  or DNS name. Http requests to the *.home address or directly to the ip address works, but not the *.local address.

Comment: Sure. *.home is probably registered by the DHCP/DNS server of your router. But I don't see how this is about Ubuntu? Some embedded device's support of mDNS is not relevant on this site.

Comment: First, try `avahi-resolve -n name.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me, the device is not mDNS ready.